# What are elliptical errors?

Tags: regression, error, elliptical-distribution

When can we have elliptical errors in linear regression?

Comment: did you try to search interweb? can you tell us what's unclear in wikipedia to you?

Comment: Good explanation from David Giles [here](http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2013/05/all-about-spherically-distributed.html).